# Selection of list box to the change other inputs

Tags: javascript

am doing a on selection of list box value it have to show it on selection of other Input may be it is text box or list box...any thing else ...so i have tried it by java script by visibility function  but its unfortunately  not work ..can body check of it...??

CSS :

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

JS :

```
function getValue(ev){ 
  var x=document.getElementById("sel");
  var A=document.getElementById("a").value();
  var B=document.getElementById("b").value();
  var C=document.getElementById("c").value();

  for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) 
  {
     if(x.options[i].selected ==true)
     {
         if(x.options[i].value == "item")
         {
             A.style.display = 'block';
             B.style.display = 'none';
             C.style.display = 'none';
         }
         if(x.options[i].value == "main") 
         {   
             A.style.display = 'none'; 
             B.style.display = 'block';
             C.style.display = 'none';
         }
         if(x.options[i].value == "sub") 
         {
             A.style.display = 'none';
             B.style.display = 'none';
             C.style.display = 'block';
         }
         if(x.options[i].value == "select") 
         {
             A.style.display = 'none';
             B.style.display = 'none';
             C.style.display = 'none';
         }   

       }
  }
}

var sel = document.getElementById('sel');

sel.addEventListener('change', getValue, false );
```

HTML :

```
<select id="sel">
   <option value ="select">--Select--</option>
   <option value ="item">Item Type Analysis</option>
   <option value ="main">Main Group Analysis</option>
   <option value ="sub">Sub Group Analysis</option>
</select>
<div id="a" class="hidden">
   <input type="textbox" name="item" id="item"/>
</div>
<div id="b" class="hidden">
   <input type="textbox" name="main" id="main"/> 
</div>
<div id="c" class="hidden">
   <input type="textbox" name="maingroup" id="maingroup"/> 
   <input type="textbox" name="subgroup" id="subgroup"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: Your question does not make much sense. Do you get any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Mistake 1

```
var A=document.getElementById("a").value();
var B=document.getElementById("b").value();
var C=document.getElementById("c").value();
```

**`value()`** is not a method, it has to be **`value`**.

## Mistake 2

Within the loop you have

```
A.style.display = 'none';
B.style.display = 'none';
C.style.display = 'block';
```

Whereas *you have declared `A`,`B` and `C` variables to holds the value **not the element***.  Change it as

```
var A=document.getElementById("a");
var B=document.getElementById("b");
var C=document.getElementById("c");
```

Check this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RDj4Z/6/)

Comment: @user3011802 Wha do you mean by without css?  in jQuery you use `.hide()` method.

Comment: @user3011802 Glad to help you, my friend :)